# How do you pass a CISampler to a Metal-based CIColorKernel?

Tags: ios, metal, cifilter

I'm trying to make a metal-based CIFilter, since Apple seems to prefer that you use this, but I'm having problems because I need to merge multiple images that may be different sizes. This means I have to use normalised coordinates and samplers to 'stretch' the various input images.

Here's an example kernel:

```
extern "C" { namespace coreimage {
    float4 stretchKernel(
                         sampler image
                         ) {
        return image.sample(image.coord());
    }
}}
```

... and I implement it like this:

```
    let arguments: [Any] = [
        CISampler(image: startingImage, options: samplerOptions)
    ]

    return kernel.apply(extent: startingImage.extent, arguments: arguments)
```

Now the weird bit. If I run this up, I get the following error:

`Argument info count 1 for function composition does not match argument count 4 in declaration of function`

It's as if samplers are being treated as four separate arguments in the kernel function, but I can only pass them as one. Am I using the right class to pass the image into the kernel? Is there something wrong with the kernel declaration? Could I perhaps use some other method to get normalised coordinates and samplers for my various images?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know why I couldn't find this out from the documentation, but the reason seems to be that the `filter` type is not compatible with `CIColorKernel`. I daresay there's a good reason, but I don't know why it wasn't made more explicitly clear. The solution is to use an ordinary `CIKernel` instead.

Comment: Yes, `CIColorKernels` are specialized kernels for processing single samples (i.e. pixels), not whole samplers (i.e. textures).